# subquery shows more that one row group by

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, inner-join

I am trying to get the data for the best 5 customers in a railway reservation system. To get that, I tried getting the max value by summing up their fare every time they make a reservation. Here is the code.

```
SELECT  c. firstName, c.lastName,MAX(r.totalFare) as Fare
FROM    customer c, Reservation r, books b
WHERE  r.resID = b.resID
  AND  c.username = b.username
  AND  r.totalfare < (SELECT sum(r1.totalfare) Revenue
                    from Reservation r1, for_res f1, customer c1,books b1
                    where r1.resID = f1.resID
                    and   c1.username = b1.username
                    and   r1.resID = b1.resID
                    group by c1.username
      )
GROUP BY    c.firstName, c.lastName, r.totalfare
ORDER BY    r.totalfare desc
LIMIT 5;
```

this throws the error:[21000][1242] Subquery returns more than 1 row

If I remove the group by from the subquery the result is:(its a tabular form)

```
Jade,Smith,1450
Jade,Smith,725
Jade,Smith,25.5
Monica,Geller,20.1
Rach,Jones,10.53
```

But that's not what I want, as you can see, I want to add the name 'Jade' with the total fare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just don't see the point for the subquery. It seems like you can get the result you want with a `sum()`

```
select c.firstname, c.lastname, sum(totalfare) as totalfare
from customer c
inner join books b on b.username = c.username
inner join reservation r on r.resid = b.resid
group by c.username
order by totalfare desc
limit 5
```

This sums all reservations of each client, and use that information to sort the resulstet. This guarantees one row per customer.

The query assumes that `username` is the primary key of table `customer`. If that's not the case, you need to add columns `firstname` and `lastname` to the `group by` clause.

Note that this uses standard joins (with the `inner join ... on` keywords) rather than old-school, implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause: these are legacy syntax, that should not be used in new code.